# How can I sort in python in ascending order?

Tags: python, sorting

I'm trying to sort values in a list but

```
  y =  [['22.344'], ['333.6575'], ['1.45'], ['122.56678'], ['33.768']]
```

when i use this command

```
    y.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
```

it doesn't sort the values in correct ascending values

```
[['1.45'], ['122.56678'], ['22.344'], ['33.768'], ['333.6575']]
```

How can i sort it in ascending order?

Comment: Please add proper tags, including your language of choice, else it shows up in everyones list. Thanks :)

Comment: It's doing lexicographical sorting. Try instead: `y.sort(key=lambda x: float(x[0]))`

Comment: @bernie why not answer?

Comment: @Darklighter: ok, sure.

Comment: Thanks @bernie now its working

Comment: Why do you have strings in your lists instead of numbers?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not show minimal research effort on the OP's part.

Comment: This is simply sort with key, or converting from string to int.  See any [tutorial](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) on Python sorting to see how this works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's doing lexicographical sorting.

Try instead:

```
y.sort(key=lambda x: float(x[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently the list is being sorted correctly. This is because the 'numbers' in the array are in fact strings. 1 comes before 2 when sorting strings and so that is why the 122.56678 is out of order.

If you can convert the strings to numbers, then the sort should work